# How to use boost::dynamic_bitset in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, boost, dev-c++, bitset

How would I go about using `boost::dynamic_bitset`?

I've tried a simple include statement: `#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>`,
but in Dev C++ I get an error saying
`"No such file or directory."`
Do I need to **download the necessary files** and include them in the project?
If so, which files?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Yes, you do need to download the necessary headers, and libraries, you will probably need to build them. Also, just a suggestion, last I heard Dev C++ was abandon, and probably does not implement C++11, which boost uses. I would suggest getting an updated I.D.E if you want to use boost.

Comment: do you have the boost library installed?

Comment: No I don't have the library installed. I'd rather just include the necessary headers in my project, if possible, rather than download the whole library. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Dev C++ can be configured to use C++ 11, but I may update my ide anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your compiler does not know where to find the boost libraries. You need to download them, extract them, and then setup your build script/development environment to point to them.

If the compiler doesn't know where the Boost libraries are it wont be able to link your code to Boost.

[Here is a getting started guide that details this.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/more/getting_started/index.html)

[And here is the download link.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.54.0/)